# Pan Segue Calls viewDidLoad Loop

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uipangesturerecognizer

My pan gesture programmatically fakes a button press. If you press the actual button, the VC's viewDidLoad runs again once, stops, and is fine. **But** when I use the pan-gesture to programmatically fake the button press, the viewDidLoad runs about seven times, then stops.

The right-edge gesture triggers the "tomorrow" state which loads a handful of times. At that point, a left-edge gesture triggers the "today" state. That also loads 4-5 times.

Any ideas? Some code below, if needed.

Pan gesture added in viewDidLoad:

```
    //Adds edge gesture depending on VC state
    if curMainList == "Today" {
        let panLeftEdgeGesture_MainVC = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panLeftEdge_toLifeList:")
        panLeftEdgeGesture_MainVC.edges = .Left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panLeftEdgeGesture_MainVC)

        let panRightEdgeGesture_MainVC = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panFromRightEdgeAction:")
        panRightEdgeGesture_MainVC.edges = .Right
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panRightEdgeGesture_MainVC)

        self.footer_LeftBtn.addTarget(self, action: "LeftFooterBtnPress", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }
    else {
        let panLeftEdgeGesture = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panFromLeftEdgeAction:")
        panLeftEdgeGesture.edges = .Left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(panLeftEdgeGesture)
    }
```

Gesture's triggered:

```
//Gestures visible when view is 'Today'
func panLeftEdge_toLifeList(sender: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToLifeLists", sender: nil)
    }
}

func panFromRightEdgeAction(sender: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
    //self.tomHdrBtnPress(tomorrowHdr)
    tomorrowHdr.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}

//Gesture added when viewing 'Tomorrow' list
func panFromLeftEdgeAction(sender: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
    //self.todayHdrBtnPress(todayHdr)
    todayHdr.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}

@IBAction func todayHdrBtnPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, animations: {
        //Header changes
        self.hdrBox.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 46/255.0, green: 173/255.0, blue: 11/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.footer_RightArrow.hidden = false
        self.footer_RightBtn.hidden = false
        }
        , completion: nil
    )
    curMainList = "TodayTask"
    currentListEntity = curMainList
    viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func tomHdrBtnPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.75, animations: {
        //Header changes
        self.hdrBox.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 49/255.0, green: 82/255.0, blue: 171/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.footer_LeftBtn.addTarget(self, action: "LeftFooterBtnPress", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        }
        , completion: nil
    )
    curMainList = "TomTask"
    currentListEntity = curMainList
    viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be "programmatically faking a button press".  And  you shouldn't be manually calling life cycle events.  You have fundamentally approached this problem completely wrong in so many ways.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to *actually* do?  What's in `viewDidLoad` that needs to be called repeatedly??

Comment: @nhgrif From the user's point of view, the pan is triggering a new page. It's actually the same VC where the header title and color changes. But to the user they will feel like they're swiping to switch pages. Nothing is supposed to run repeatedly. See how it updates the list variable? When the viewDidLoad runs it will notice that variable changed and will load the header and table with different values.

Comment: That logic shouldn't be in `viewDidLoad`.  `viewDidLoad` *maybe* calls a method with that logic in it, but you should ***never*** be manually calling life cycle events.  *And* you should also ***never*** be programmatically tapping buttons like this (short of doing automated UI testing).

Comment: @nhgrif I can guess that life cycle events like viewDidLoad shouldn't be called, just out of principal. But in effect, I'm changing pages. The header changes, the table changes, and the footer changes. So why wouldn't I want my viewDidLoad to run again and change it all? And what's the peril of programmatically tapping a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that pan gestures are continuous gestures (meaning that as you move your finger, the handler is called repeatedly). For a pan gesture, it's called once with a `gesture.state` of `.Began`, repeated with a `state` of `.Changed` as the user's finger moves, and the finally with a `state` of `.Ended` or `.Cancelled` when the user stops the gesture.

So, you generally would not trigger an `animateWithDuration` from a continuous gesture. You just update the state based upon, for example, `gesture.translationInView()` or what have you. Just update the views immediately to reflect the updated pan and it's called so frequently, that it ends up rendering something that feels like an animation, but it's really just a sequence of updates linked to continuous flow of updates your gesture recognizer's handler receives as the user progresses in their gesture.

The only time you would animate within a continuous gesture is upon `.Ended` or `.Cancelled`, to complete the animation. For example, maybe the user drags their finger half way across, so on `.Changed` you just update the view immediately without any animation, but when they lift their finger (i.e. the gesture handler receive `.Ended`), you might animate completion to the view's final state.

Bottom line, the handling in gesture recognizers is a very different mechanism for animation that might result from a button (in which you call the `animateWithDuration` methods once to initiate an animation that UIKit then takes care of for you). It's best not to conflate these two very different ways of updating/animating the UI.

---

You also are performing a segue in one of your pan handlers. If you want to have a segue performed interactively as you pan, you should refer to WWDC 2013 video [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-218/), which shows how you can combine an animation controller (which dictates the nature of the animation) with an interaction controller (which links the progress of the gesture with the animation controller). But in this pattern, you perform the segue once and only once, and merely update the `UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition` in the gesture, which will link the progress of the transition with the user's finger.
`

Comment: Thank you! My new function looks like this:                                              func panFromLeftEdgeAction(sender: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch (sender.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended: